# run some scripts or all scripts in ruby rake

Tags: ruby, webdriver, rake

How can I do the scenario below: (the purpose is to be able to run all selenium scripts I have or only run some scripts I want if I pass test files as arguments from terminal window with the below code and scenario:

if test files are passed in terminal window 
then system will run below codes:

```
scripts = ENV[scripts].plit(',')
FileList[scripts].each { |file|
system("ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out")}
```

if test files are NOT passed in terminal window (it means I want to run all scripts I have in my test suite), then system will run below codes:

```
FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file|
system("ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, can you just use an `if` statement?

```
task :default do
  if ENV[scripts]
    scripts = ENV[scripts].split(',')
    FileList[scripts].each { |file|
    system("ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out")}
  else
    FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file|
    system("ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out")}
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree with this answer as long as the OP really means to use an environment variable (e.g. scripts=some_test; ruby myscript.rb). If the OP is actually wanting to pass the scripts as arguments, he'll need to iterate over ARGV instead of accessing ENV[scripts].

Comment: @johnnycakes: Yes, your great answer is exactly what I want to do, thanks so much.